# NetSuite Can not upload file in Editor

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to upload a file in Editor,

I got a message to change password: ":The password is no longer valid. Please enter your current password."
I entered my password (I tried the master password and also my password to login to NetSuite),
But then i got this  message again.

When I tried to cancel,
I got  an error: "The remote server returned an error:Invalid login attempt."

What should I do?

Comment: Your reference to a 'master password' sounds like you're talking about the Eclipse SuiteCloud IDE - can you confirm?

Comment: Yes. Eclipse SuiteCloud IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I've had this in the past it has always been the NetSuite login password which was incorrect - usually because the password had expired and been changed, but not updated in Eclipse.  So focus on that first, then check the settings in `NetSuite > Manage Environments` and `NetSuite > Manage Accounts` to ensure you have the correct URLs and email addresses set.

If you continue to get the same error, go to `NetSuite > Troubleshoot > Reset Master Password and Account Information`.  Read the warning that appears then click `OK`.  After Eclipse restarts you can then go to `NetSuite > Setup Wizard` to set up your master password and account information again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I tried your answer  but I still get the same error,
What else should I check?

Comment: BTW, 
Now, I have  tried to upload a file in editor with another account and another environment
(I have the environment of the NetSuite course).
And I succeeded, 
I thought it might have something to do with my user settings in NetSuite.

I am an administrator What else should I set up?

Comment: I found the problem
The reason is :I am an administrator,  so I have to login with Two-Factor Authentication
And that's what caused the problem.
When I defined myself as a role that did not require Two-Factor Authentication, 
I was able to upload the file
Thanks

Comment: Which role did you use to get around the two-factor authentication issue?

Comment: I set up a SDF Developer role as per the instructions in [this SuiteAnswers article](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/51761) and use that role in the project settings.